# Finding the length of the path of a point in a coordinate system which rotates in another coordinate system

Tags: rotations, interpolation

I have a point in a 3D coordinate system 1 (CS1). There can be two situations: the point is constant or the point is moving along a straight line from one known position to another at constant speed.

The CS1 is rotating in another (static) 3D coordinate system (CS2). The rotations of CS1 are known, i.e. the starting and ending angles are known, and the angular speeds are constant, so we can get a precise rotation matrix at any moment of time.

I need to find the length of the point's trajectory in the CS2.

In the simplest case, when the point isn't moving in CS1 and CS1 is rotating around one axis of CS2, the trajectory is a simple arc. In more complex cases, my current solution is to find a few points along the way (having point's position in CS1 and rotation angles of CS1 in CS2) and interpolate them with cubic spline, then get the length of the spline.

Is there a more precise and/or straightforward way to find the trajectory of the point in CS2? Thanks.

Comment: If I am right, the trajectory is an Archimede's spiral, which is rectifiable. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html

Comment: Thanks Bobby, I forgot to mention that both CS are 3D (updated the post)

Comment: Then in general the curve is embedded in the surface of an hyperboloid of one sheet. You need to establish the parametric equations and try to integrate the element of arc. (Make the two known points on the line rotate about the rotation axis and linearly interpolate between them at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend that you just calculate a large number of points and then interpolate them with a polyline. If you need more accuracy, use more points. The nice thing about polylines is that their arclength are very easy to calculate.

Your idea of using a (cubic) spline won’t help very much, because computing the length of a cubic spline requires numerical integration techniques.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

WLOG one of the points describes a unit circle in the plane $XY$ and the second point a circle in a parallel plane, with some phase difference but at the same unit angular speed.

$$P(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0),$$
$$Q(t)=(r\cos(t-t_0),r\sin(t-t_0),z_0).$$

Now a point that travels between them at constant speed has the coordinates
$$R(t)=(1-v(t-t_1))P(t)+v(t-t_1)Q(t)$$
and
$$\dot R(t)=-vP(t)+vQ(t)+(1-v(t-t_1))\dot P(t)+v(t-t_1)\dot Q(t).$$

After simplification, the element of arc seems to be just the square root of a quadratic trinomial, and this has an analytical antiderivative. But you will definitely need a CAS.

Comment: Thank you, it is not exactly what I meant but there's something to think about